# how set admin url in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to change my wordpress login url .I have changed the wp-login.php file and replaced the wp-login to 'siteadmin' it is working for the admin but it is stopping the site login functionality of the members . site members can't login .I have also used the 'lock admin url'
it worked but same problem.Please let me know how can I do it without effect the member.login

admin url: http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin

```
 I want:
```

http://yourdomian.com/siteadmin

Answer (score 0):

On the `Settings->General` screen in a single site installation of WordPress, there are two fields named "`WordPress address (URL)`" and "`Site address (URL)`". These are also known as the "Home" and "Site URL" settings. They are important settings, since they control where WordPress thinks your site is located. They control the display of the URL in the admin section of your page as well as the front end, and are used throughout the WordPress code.

from http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: I want to change the admin url only.

Comment: @RohitSharma also check http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4789/changing-the-wp-admin-url-to-whatever-i-want

Answer (score 0):

Changes in your .htaccess file

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule ^siteadmin$ http://www.yourdomain.com/wp-login.php [NC,L]
    RewriteBase /internal/users/manu/style/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

   </IfModule>
```

or you can install http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by installing a plugin something like 'HC Custom WP-Admin URL'. It will provide an option in permalinks to change the admin url parameter.